# Intel graphics and Compiz

Tags: compiz, intel-graphics

I'm having trouble with Compiz.

First, I was using the vesa drivers, so Compiz failed to start. I switched to intel by removing the vesa packages, installing libgl1-mesa-dri and libgl1-mesa-dlx along with xserver-xorg-vide-intel, and now Compiz starts but is incredibly glitchy. Switching workspaces makes everything blink uncontrollably, for example. I don't know what to try next.

Some diagnostic info:

```
inxi -Gx
Graphics:  Card: Intel Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0 
           X.Org 1.10.4 drivers intel,fbdev Resolution 1366x768@76.0hz 
           GLX Renderer Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x209) GLX Version 2.1 Mesa 8.1-devel (git-6e738d3 oneiric-oibaf-ppa) Direct Rendering Yes
```

The compiz-check script I found scattered all over the web reports:

```
./compiz-check 

Gathering information about your system...

 Distribution:          Linux Mint 
 Desktop environment:   GNOME
 Graphics chip:         Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
 Driver in use:         fbdev
 Rendering method:      AIGLX

Checking if it's possible to run Compiz on your system...

 Checking for texture_from_pixmap...               [ OK ]
 Checking for non power of two support...          [ OK ]
 Checking for composite extension...               [ OK ]
 Checking for FBConfig...                          [ OK ]
 Checking for hardware/setup problems...           [ OK ]
```

To be fair, I did get a warning about me having a weird graphics card, and possible poor Compiz reliability. Can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many different tries, adding `acpi_osi=` to the kernel command-line in GRUB fixed my problem. For future reference:

**To give this a one-shot try**

1. Hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> during boot (this lands you in the GRUB menu if its skipped by default)
2. Put the cursor over the Mint entry (usually the first) and press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit it
3. Add`acpi_osi` to the options in the line that begins with "linux" (usually after `quiet nosplash`)

If this works, you'll want to avoid having to make this change manually every time you boot.

**To set this permanently**

1. Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` (with sudo), and add `acpi_osi=` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
   ```
2. Run `grub-update` as root

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Since the marked answer did not prove successful for me (I don't know why because I have the exact same problem and card as OP), I had to try several different things. At the end of it, I arrived at a handy software called **Xdiagnose** which set the grub boot parameters for me. You can try it out to suit your needs.

For me, It applied the following commands:

`plymouth:debug vesafb.invalid=1 nomodeset=1 nopat`

Turns out, the splash graphics at the beginning was starting to stir trouble out of nowhere, all of a sudden. My selections at Xdiagnose are as follows:

> [  ] Extra graphics debug messages
>   [X] Display boot messages
>   [X] Enable automatic crash bug reporting
>   [X] Disable bootloader graphics
>   [X] Disable VESA framebuffer driver
>   [X] Disable PAT memory